# Do event receviers à la SharePoint exist in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have a colleague who claims that SharePoint's event receivers is a great functionality which probably exists for Dynamics CRM. I claim otherwise. According to Google I claim right but, to be humble, I'm checking with the community.

Specifically, we're looking for ways to automatically update a page when e.g. a new instance of *Contact* has been created on another client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically an event receiver is analogous to a CRM plugin so you're kind of both right.  You win though if the requirement was for event broadcast to all connected clients on a predetermined trigger as there is no such technology in any release of CRM to date.  If you wanted to implement something to replicate this feature it shouldn't be too difficult to do using SignalR.

Comment: **I WIN!**     +1 because *SinglarR* was exactly my suggestion too (there are of course other frameworks too, but still - great minds think alike).      :D